# Dynamic method dispatch in java and c++

Tags: java, c++, dynamic

In this C++ program,

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{

    public:

    Base()
    {
        cout<<"\n\nBase ctr";
        fun();
    }  

    virtual void fun()
    {
        cout<<"\n\nBase's fun()";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:

    Derived()
    {
        cout<<"\n\nDerived ctr";
        fun();
    }

    virtual void fun()
    {
        cout<<"\n\nDerived's fun()";
    }
};
    int main()
    {
        Derived obj;
        return 0;
    }
```

when calling a virtual function from Base class's constructor using Derived class object, Base's class fun() gets called,

output::
Base ctr

Base's fun()

Derived ctr

Derived's fun()

reason in explained [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.5)
  but

in this java program,

```
class Base
{
    Base()
    {
        System.out.println( "\n\nBase ctr" );
        fun();
    }
    void fun()
    {
        System.out.println( "\n\nBase's fun()" );
    }
}

class Derived extends Base
{
    int a=1;

    Derived()
    {
        System.out.println( "\n\nDerived ctr a = "+a );

        a=8;
        fun();
    }

    void fun()
    {
       System.out.println( "\n\nDerived's fun() a = "+a );
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       Derived obj = new Derived();
    }
}
```

output is ::
Base ctr

Derived's fun() a = 0

Derived ctr a = 1

Derived's fun() a = 8

here, Derived class fun() is being called, so  the [constraint](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.5) applied to c++ program, is not applicable to JAVA program. why?

Comment: Because... they're different languages and not the same set of rules apply?

Comment: This rule makes it more complicated to reason about program behavior because it special-cases method invocation rules. Java is all about simple rules.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The C++ way makes more sense when you think about it. I recall reading that Java programmers should avoid calling virtual methods in constructors for precisely this reason.

Comment: @Pubby Yes, it makes more sense and yes, Java devs tend to write buggy idioms due to the lack of this rule. However, it is still true that this and many other such rules are absent from Java due to the design choice to keep it simple.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I don't think the rule is much more complex, actually is simpler to reason about. In the constructor of X, only a final overrider at level X or above will be called in C++, while in Java you cannot reason about what overrider will be called. Add to the mix the fact that in Java *all* functions are virtual (unless marked otherwise) and what you get is that if your constructor calls any function you cannot possibly reason about what the program will do at runtime when you are working on the base X

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Look at it this way: would the JLS be shorter or longer if it contained that rule?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: The length of the specification document is the **worst** excuse ever to make a design decision on a language. It is similar to saying that a car manufacturer does not need to verify the brakes because it would have a higher cost on construction... The cost of the specification falls solely on the specification committee and the compiler implementors, and I don't think the implementation of either option is more complex than the others...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas calling a method in Base when Derived overrides it may actually confuse developers, the ability to reason about what method is absent during the objects lifetime, this is not a bug but a feature of virtual method invocation. Also any java IDE (maybe even the compiler) will warn against virtual method calls in the ctor.

Comment: @josefx: I don't understand this: *the ability to reason about what method is absent during the objects lifetime*, and I don't see how this can be considered a *feature* on Java side. What would be the advantage of having the call being dispatched to a yet to be constructed instance? Please expand. Reasoning in C++ is much simpler (well, virtual/multiple inheritance aside :)). Also: *any Java IDE ... will warn against virtual method calls*... do they warn on all calls to *any* non-final method? (I have to admit I haven't coded Java in the last 8 years)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Every Java dev should be familiar with the JLS. You don't mean to imply it's literature only for language implementors? I may or may not agree with your position, but it is a fact that many things in Java are crippled in favor of simplicity. No unsigned integers, covariant array types, very strict boolean logic, explicit casts even in the most obvious situations, only final vars accessible in anonymous classes, ...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas in java a virtual method invocation always behaves like a virtual method invocation, in c++ this behavior changes between object construction and the remaining lifetime (called methods depend on which state the ctor is in). I would call consistent behavior a feature - I never called the problems with reasoning about virtual method calls a java feature it is a "feature" of any language that has virtual method calls. java advantage: the developer of a Derived class may want to change parts of how Base is initialized (as with anything there are alternative ways to do this)

Comment: @josefx That's exactly my thought -- with the rule in debate here you'd get one specific case where arguably it is simpler to reason, and a ton of other cases where it turns into a bloody mess. The exact same line of code, with the exact same parameter values, having different results depending on caller?? Now THAT's a confusing rule, if there ever was one.

Comment: @josefx: In Java, in a derived type that overrides a member of the base, you have no guarantee about the invariants of your type, as the method can be called *before* the constructor sets the invariants for the first time. Consider the code sample I just added the question. Ask a few of your co-workers what they would expect the program to do and then think how much sense this makes.

Comment: David, the problem of leaked `this` exists independently of overriding method calls. If you call a `private` or even `public final` method from your constructor, the same problem arises. The worst nightmare is when you manage to publish your `this` to another thread. That thread is not guaranteed to **ever** witness your object in a consistent state. So once again, the C++ rule in question would a) add complexity and b) not fix a thing for Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two languages take a different approach to dynamic dispatch. In C++ it will only dispatch to a fully constructed object. That is handled by *changing* the type of the object during construction as the different levels of the hierarchy constructor *start* executing. Java on the other hand, considers the object to be of the most derived type before even starting the base-most constructor.

The problem with the Java approach is that it might actually be executing code on an object that has not yet been constructed. Consider that the derived type had a field initialized to X, and that it is accessed/updated in a method. Calling that method on the base object would access the member before the constructor has initialized it.

At any rate, you should avoid calling a virtual function in the constructor or destructor of your object in either language.

---

Illustrative example:

```
public class Base {
   public final int x;
   public Base() { 
      x = foo();
   }
   int foo() { return 1; }
}
public class Derived extends Base {
   public final int y;
   public Derived() {
      y = 2;
   }
   int foo() { return y; }
}
Derived d = new Derived();
assert( d.x == d.y );                      // Can this ever fail?
```

In this code, we have 2 final `int`, and the code seems simple enough to reason about. Can the `assert` ever fail?

Comment: ... and all this begs the question: **Why** did its creators choose this behavior for Java?

Comment: It is a design choice, and it allows for other constructs, like for example initializing a `final` reference in the constructor based on an overrider. I don't believe that to be the reason, as dependency injection would be a better fit for this use case (i.e. the derived type would pass the value to the base constructor, making it cleaner even if more coding is involved). At any rate you would have to ask those that designed the language :)

Comment: I guess we have a choice in all questions of this type, then: stay philosophically silent or try to second-guess the designers. People usually end up indulging in the latter.

Comment: Java compiler statically ensures all final fields are initialized -- and only initialized. That rules out overridable methods. But, since a method can be called anytime, not only from a constructor, that rules out **all** methods and we get to the fact: all final fields must be initialized within the constructor code.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Does it? Or does the order of initialization of a final depend on how it is initialized? `class X extends B { final int a; final int b = 1; X() { a = 1; }}` Will the behavior be the same for `a` and `b`? I seem to recall that I tested this long time ago and got different results...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Just for the sake of it I tried it, and it does depend on how you initialize the `final` fields. Now tell me, how is this rule simpler than 'during construction and destruction, virtual function calls will not be dispatched below the type of the object being constructed'?

Comment: Sorry, not following. You initialized a and b to 1. They are now both 1. What do you mean?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Say that this is the derived type, and also say that a function `f` printed the two values. Consider that the base constructor called the function `f`. What would be the output of constructing an object of this derived type? (i.e. what are the values of `a` and `b` during construction of the base?)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I have updated the answer with an illustrative example of why this might be surprising to some.

Comment: Yes, you are demonstrating the classic example of what we talked about  at the outset, the problem of the leaked `this`. But the argument that Java should have a rule added that makes this specific example easier to reason about, and at the same time makes a mess out of many other examples, is not particularly sound.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas  A counter example would be int foo(){return 2;} which works as expected in java but fails in c++. Also responding to your comment from before java has guarantees that an uninitialized field will contain its default value, so x will always be set to the default value of y, which is 0.

Comment: @josefx: This is becoming a philosophical discussion. My claim is that when you write a base class, and you decide to factor out some of the initialization to a function, you no longer know how your class is going to be initialized in Java (a derived type might change the semantics of your constructor), while in C++ you know exactly what the state of the object will be after the constructor completes. To me that is more important than the potential for extension points (which I have stated before can be refactored into arguments to the constructor itself)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas the not knowing what happens to your object is a feature of virtual methods - c++ only has a special case for initialization but it behaves the same unknown way for everything else. I do believe that both the java way and the c++ way have their own set of pros and cons (its like big/little endian - no ultimate right way to do it that would make everyone happy) and without the actual creators of java/c++ its almost impossible to find out why they choose to do it the way it is.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I'll give you a a counterexample very similar to yours with factoring out initialization: what if you already have an init method and later decide you'll need that to be a two-phase process -- first lightweight construction, then real init later, when some precondition is satisfied, or when the object is actually used? With the C++ rule, suddenly your nice setup stops working because you are now outside the dynamic scope of a constructor. Boom, WTF, debug, scratch head...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: First I would not do 2-phase initialization, but let's roll with the idea. In C++, unlike Java, not all methods are `virtual`, since there is no need for `init` to be polymorphic, then it would not be virtual. No surprises there. If you need to provide an `init` at the derived type (this is getting ugly enough that I would not agree to it in a code review), you can provide a different `init` member function in derived that calls the base `init` and then completes initialization. No surprises here either.

Comment: I congratulate you on good design. In good design you'd never leak a `this` out of Java constructor. Your Java example above is catastrophic design and it's obvious from a mile's distance. So clearly we're not discussing good design here, but potential for surprising behavior.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I don't quite understand what you are talking about, what is the `this` that is leaked from which constructor? At any rate, because the effect of the code is not obvious, I do agree that it is not a good design, it is **never** a good design to call a polymorphic function from a constructor. Now if you are talking about the last example (or actually the C++ approach), there is no call to a polymorphic function, and I don't see why you claim that `this` is leaked out of the constructor.

Comment: `public Base() { 
      x = foo();
   }` -- here you are leaking `this` since `foo` is an overridable instance method (`foo` obviously has access to `this`).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Which basically means that you are claiming that the Java approach of dispatching to the final overrider at all times sensible **but** at the same time stating that doing so is a bad design. I agree on the second part, which is why I prefer the approach of not letting that happen in the language at all. The `this` pointer will not be *leaked* (I am using the term here to refer to *passing a pointer of type T to a function that expects it to be of a different type). That is, in C++, in the constructor you can use `this` only as a pointer to a **valid fully constructed** object.

Comment: If by "final overrider" you mean something like `@Override public final ...`, I don't see myself mentioning that. The closest I can see is mentioning a `public final` method in the context of stating that dispatching to it from a constructor is a case of a leaked `this`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: *final overrider* is a C++ term, I should have explained. In a *complete object*, the *final overrider* for a particular virtual method is the implementation of that method that is further away from the base, that is, the *final overrider* is the actual method that will be called if dynamic dispatch is used to call that virtual function. Fancy name, common concept. I used the term in an attempt to separate the *override* at the level on which the constructor is being called from the last override in the inheritance chain that can be in an *more derived* (unconstructed) type.

Comment: I see. This thread has been beaten to death by now, but I'll give one last clarification: at the JLS level it is sensible not to complicate method dispatch rules and at the code design level it is not sensible to leak a `this` in any case, with a `this` leaked to a publicly overridable method being the nastiest variant of the problem.